# ASP.NET Eventhandler Not working

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I have a pretty straight forward dynamically generated asp page.  This is my first time using dynamically generated asp controls.  The table renders correctly, however when I click on the "Query" button I cannot get the event to connect to the "OnClick" method.  I get a webpage error "'ButtonClick' is undefined".  I have stripped and simplified the code down for brevity.

DeviceStatus.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Device Status" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Secure.master"
'AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DeviceStatus.aspx.cs" Inherits="Devices" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent"></asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<div id="selectDiv" runat="server"></div>

</asp:Content>
```

DeviceStatus.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


public partial class Devices : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    int i, NumberOfDevices = 3;
    string Contents;
    string[] number = new string[] { "1", "2", "3"};
    string[] name = new string[] {"mike", "bob", "cindy"};
    string[] location = new string[] { "Austin", "Miami", "Atlanta" };     

    // Create event binding
    PlaceHolder Placeholder1 = new PlaceHolder();
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Text = "Click";
    button.Click += new System.EventHandler(ButtonClick);
    Placeholder1.Controls.Add(button);

    //Create Form and table header
    Contents = "<form runat=\"server\"><table border=\"1\" >";
    Contents += "<tr><th>Select</th><th>Number</th><th>Name</th><th>Status</tr>";

    // Repeat for each table row
    for (i = 0; i < NumberOfDevices; i++) {

        // Creat each row
        Contents += "<tr><td><asp:Button ID=\"row" + i + "\""    
             + "runat=\"server\"OnClick=\"ButtonClick\" >Query</asp:Button></td>"
             + "<td>" + number[i] + "</td><td>" + name[i] + "</td><td>"
             + location[i] + "</td></tr>";
    }

    // Cleanup
    Contents += "</table>";
    Contents += "<asp:PlaceHolder ID=\"Placeholder1\" runat=\"server\"></asp:PlaceHolder>";
    Contents += "</form>";
    Contents += "</asp:Content>";

    //Place dynamic asp controls in webpage
    selectDiv.InnerHtml = Contents; 
}


protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("DataRendering.aspx");
}



}
```

Comment: This is HTML#.  HTML# is using C# to output HTML (especially ASP controls) to the page.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Let's start there.

Comment: You cannot create an asp.net control from codebehind like that. Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx

Comment: Looking more at this, I don't think you need to dynamically generate anything.  Just use a GridView with a Select Column.

Comment: Hello Garrison...There is a ton of code before and after this little snippet but basically I am getting an serialized xml object from a web service and I want to render a table of the deserialized xml object.  The table has a button in the first column that when clicked will got to ButtonClick.  I uniquely id each row with a ID=row# so I can identify which row is clicked.  The ButtonClick then sorts out the row data, does some work then redirects to a new page.  I have pulled all of that code out to make it more readable.

Comment: Hello Garrison...Yes, I will take a look at Gridview.  I have used it before a couple of years back.  However, can you identify what I am doing wrong here.  It has application elsewhere in my code...Thanks.

Comment: @SteveMansfield Hanlet showed you what you are doing wrong... you can't create controls like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with Garrison's suggestion.  It took some time to get through the code to figure it out but once completed was the most straight forward solution.  Thanks everyone for contributing.